# How to store and access sessions in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, session

I'm doing an advanced project with ASP .NET Sessions, I would like to know:

**A) What do I add exactly to my web.config to enable full session writing to the database server.**

**B) What table would the sessions be stored in once enabled?  So far I'm only aware that the default is "TempDB".**

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604

Comment: Step-by-step (including the answer for **B** ): http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3595766/Storing-Session-State-in-a-SQL-Server-Database.htm

Comment: @JohnSaunders Leave my post alone, that's ridiculous.
Thanks Andre, that support article is the best thing I've seen and I can't believe I didn't find that on google.  I would award you the answer if you posted it.  Thanks so much.  At least Antonio didn't remove my "Thanks!"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find all configuration details on [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) article. Go to section `SQL Server Mode`

This is the required configuration

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="StateServer"
      stateConnectionString="tcpip=SampleStateServer:42424"
      cookieless="false"
      timeout="20"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Here you have some details about where the session information is stored and how to change the default location. For more details, check [this article](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3595766/Storing-Session-State-in-a-SQL-Server-Database.htm) as Andre Calil suggested.

> By default, the Aspnet_regsql.exe tool will create a database named ASPState containing stored procedures that support SQLServer mode. Session data itself is stored in the tempdb database by default. You can optionally use the -sstype option to change the storage location of session data

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps mentioned at below link:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308100